# cc1: error: bad value (armv5) for -march= switch

Tags: cross-compiling, u-boot, beagleboneblack

I am compiling u-boot for beagle bone black as per the steps mentioned on this link

[http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-Bootloader:U-Boot](http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-Bootloader%3aU-Boot)

and getting the following error.

> cc1: error: bad value (armv5) for -march= switch

can anyone help me in finding the reason for this error?
I guess this is because of gcc not supporting armv7-a still not sure.

thanks,
sumit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you type the exact command shown on eewiki.net page, there would be a problem if you do not have env var CC set. I prefer the following, it assumes you have reasonably current install of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc as your cross toolchain (adjust if you have something different)

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
export ARCH=arm
make am335x_evm_config
make
```

Comment: I had the same problem only when running the line:
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC}

I tried your suggestion but got another error: 
    arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc not found

Could you please give me any suggestions on why this happens?

Comment: Happened to me when u-boot wasn't with the right ownership. Chown solved it :)